# prepopulated static data, to ship in my iOS app

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an app that shows static data and images, it will never update or change its content ( client's request ), The client will provide all the data, I am exploring possible ways of doing this, I've read articles close to what I am trying to accomplish that do this by 
prepopulating a sqlite DB, and using coredata to load it. 
Is this the best approach? This app never has to connect online to get new data or updates, just show whatever it contains locally.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work. Use core data, build the app in the simulator. Then go into the simulator folder, copy the sqlite into the app and link to it in the app delegate. At that point it will ship with the app.

For images you should store in your app's folder as opposed to putting in core data, then put the url to the image or document in your entity (if you need it). Use NSFileManager to store docs and images in your app's folder.

Comment: To whit, it depends on how much data and what the data is. A plist or a few might suffice.

Comment: YEah I am talking about 700 rows, so plist is out of the question.

Comment: A binary plist would probably be fine for that, although there's nothing wrong with using sqlite. At 700 rows even a JSON file would probably be fast enough.

Comment: really? I would love using Json, well when I say 700 rows, that translates to 700 Json object, each object having 4-5 properties. Hving known that you think JSON i still a viable option? At what number of rows would you say a SQLite DB is needed?

Comment: i think it also dependsnon what you want to do (searching, relationships, etc). CD is very good at those.